# $f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}} & \text{ if } x\neq 0 \\ 0& \text{ if } x= 0\end{cases}$ is not equal to its Maclaurin Series

Tags: taylor-expansion

$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}} & \text{ if } x\neq 0 \\ 0& \text{ if } x= 0\end{cases}$ is not equal to its Maclaurin Series, which is $e^{-1/x^2}=1-\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{2!x^4}-\dfrac{1}{3!x^6}+\ldots$. Why is that? Any hints?

Comment: That is not the Maclaurin series. The Maclaurin series is $0$.

Comment: why is The Mmaclaurin series is zero? because $f(x)=0$ when $x=0$?

Comment: Not only that, also all derivatives $f^{(n)}(0)$ are zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, the MacLaurin series must have the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$, so what you write is *not* a MacLaurin series.

However, the MacLaurin series of this function is the null series, since $D^n f(0)=0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $f$ is not the null function, we deduce that $f$ does not coincide with its MacLaurin series. No surprise: we have found a $C^\infty$ function that is not analytic. It is interesting, isn't it?

Comment: So the MacLaurin Series is effectively nonexistance because $f(0)=0$?

Comment: @V150 No, you calculate a Maclaurin series with derivatives.

Comment: **Theorem.** There is a smooth function that cannot be expanded in a MacLaurin series. Actually, you have proved this result!

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is not the Maclaurin series for your function.

By definition, the MacLaurin series of $f$ around $x=0$ is $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\cdot x^n.$$

Now, apply this definition to the function $f$ from your question. What do you get?

Comment: I still don't get it... What can I do? when I differentiate $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$, I can't get f'(0).

Comment: @V150: instead of using rules of differentiation, try using the original definition of the derivative instead. $f'(x) = (f(x+h)-f(x))/h$